# Docker の centos:centos6 イメージで mysql 5.6 を動作させるには

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql, docker

新しく参加した Rails プロジェクトを DockerToolbox で動作させたいと思っています。
Rails のバージョンは 4.0.0 です。

```
# ...省略 Docker Toolbox のセットアップ...

$ git clone path/to/repository.git project
$ cd project
# gem をインストール
$ bundle --path vendor/bundle
# fig を起動
$ fig up -d
# migration を実行（DBは作成済み）
$ rake db:migrate
```

上記 rake タスクが失敗してしまいます。
エラー内容は下記のとおりです。

```
Mysql2::Error: All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead: ...
```

エラーメッセージで調べると[参考](http://qiita.com/the40san/items/b9130a9bdfb41c023d09)の通り、 MySQL のバージョンが 5.7.3 以降の場合、 activerecord の実装が原因で MySQL がエラーを吐くようです。

そこで、MySQL のバージョンを 5.6 系にしようとしたのですが、うまくできません。
fig.yml と mysql の Dockerfile は下記の通りです。

**fig.yml**

```
mysql:
  build: ./docker/mysql
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
  volumes_from:
    - data
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
data:
  image: centos:centos6
  command: /bin/bash
  volumes:
    - /data
    - /var/lib/mysql
```

**docker/mysql/Dockerfile**

```
FROM mysql:5.6

RUN cp -p /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Tokyo /etc/localtime

ADD config/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf
```

この状態でこうなります。

```
$ fig build
$ fig up -d
$ fig ps
# =>             Name                          Command               State                 Ports
# => ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# => app_data_1            /bin/bash                        Exit 0
# => app_mysql_1           /entrypoint.sh mysqld            Exit 1
#
```

`fig logs` の結果はこうです。

```
mysql_1         | mkdir: cannot create directory '': No such file or directory
```

おそらく[ここ](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/5.6/docker-entrypoint.sh#L20)でエラーとなっているのだろう、まではわかったのですが、これから先がどうすれば良いか皆目わかりません。

Comment: シェル上で `which mysqld` を実行すると何か表示されますか？

Comment: environment: - DATADIR=/var/lib/msql を追加してみるとどうなりますか？

Comment: [そこ](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/5.6/docker-entrypoint.sh#L20)を見ると、パス内に `mysqld` が見つからないためだと思われますので、例えば `PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH rake db:migrate` とすると良いかも知れません。なお、`mysqld` が置かれているディレクトリが `/usr/sbin` ではない場合は、実際のディレクトリを指定してください。

Comment: @argus
現状、そもそもmysqld用のコンテナ自体が以上終了しているため、シェルへ接続できません。
イメージを `From mysql` にして `mysql` が実行されているコンテナ内で `which mysqld` を実行すると `/usr/sbin/mysqld` と表示されました。
`rake` コマンドにパスを指定しても `mysqld` が動いているのはコンテナの中ですのでやはり解決には至りませんでした。

@ken.sakanakana 
状況は変わりませんでした。。

Answer (score 1):

docker の実行環境を教えていただいてもよいでしょうか。
rake db:migrate の実行がコンテナ内でのみ可能な環境になっているのかもしれないのでは、と考えました。

私の実行環境は OSX 上の docker-machine に boot2docker を使用しています。この環境で docker hub の mysql で案内されていた mysqld の単体起動を以下のように行いました。

```
 % docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:5.6
```

この mysqld は docker-machine の仮想ホスト(私はVirtualBoxです)の中から 3306/tcp ポートが見える形になり、このコマンドを実行した Terminal 上では 3306/tcp ポートが見えません。

railsアプリケーションを docker コンテナ内に配備すると実行できるかもしれません。

```
% docker run -it --link some-mysql:mysql --rm your-rails-app-container 'rake db:create && rake db:migrate && rails s'
```

以上です。

Comment: 今更ですが、回答ありがとうございました。
同じく boot2docker （docker-machine）でセットアップした VirtualBox 内のdockerコンテナで動かしている mysql サーバーです。普通に 3306 ポートはローカルマシンから見えていたはずです。。
結局、この問題は Rails をバージョンアップして新しいバージョンの mysql を使うことで解決しました。